# C++ String to double conversion using stringstream gives precision error

Tags: c++, visual-c++, precision

This is a snippet of my code. I need some help in removing the error shown below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    char doubleStr[] = "5.2";
    double d = 0.0;
    std::stringstream stream (doubleStr);
    stream >> d;
    std::cout << d << std::endl;
    std::cout << (d <= 5.2);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives output:

```
5.200000000002
0
```

How to remove this precision error? Can I use std::setprecision() to solve the issue?

Comment: You will almost always have some inprecision when storing doubles. The exact value "5.2" cannot be stored in a double. With `std::setprecision` you should be able to show less digits, which will look "as if" it was exactly 5.2

Comment: @oLen Something more complicated than that is going on here. Floating point behaviour is predictable and deterministic, just tricky to understand sometimes. Can you explain why parsing `"5.2"` into a `double` is leading to a value not equal to the `double` literal `5.2`? I think they should result in the same double representation, if the compiler and the stream library are both implemented correctly. With gcc 4.9.2, that comparison comes up true.

Comment: What compiler+os are you using? With gcc 4.9.2, 64bit Linux, I see that comparison coming up true.

Comment: This must just be a code snipit. The default precision for a stream is 6: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision Thus this code should output: "5.2\n1" [[Live Example](http://ideone.com/ibCqpx)]

Comment: This is a small part of my code, the char stream and the double "5.2" are a result of some processing. The double I used for comparison is precisely 5.2. When I wanted it to be compared to the char stream "5.2" I got the above conclusion. I also ran the above code on ideone.com I got 5.2 and 1. I am using vc13 and windows machine

Answer (score 3):

[`numeric_limits<double>::digits10`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25785968/2642059) can be used to find the number of digits that are uniquely representable by a `double`.

I see you've tagged your question with Visual Studio. You can test this code on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ to get Visual Studio's number of uniquely representable digits for a `double`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() { std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 << std::endl; }
```

This code will *not* output 2 it will output:

> 15

Which means that any `double` up to 14 decimal places *will* survive the round trip through a `stringstream` and still be equal to itself.

---

The above means that there is something you are not including in your example that is causing the round trip failure, or you are using non-standard source files that are not IEEE compliant. (For example I can do a [live example on gcc](http://ideone.com/ibCqpx) that gives a contrary output to yours, and running the same code on Visual Studio disagrees with your output.)

Either way, for any uniquely representable `double` (like 5.2), you can ensure that round trip success through a `stringstream` by setting the precision. Precision is a sticky modifier, so you'll only need to set it once after stream construction. In your example you use `stringstream stream` so before you work with `stream` you'd need to set this modifier:

```
stream.precision(numeric_limits<double>::digits10 - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this in order to show the double number in the right way:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
int main()
{
    char doubleStr[] = "5.2";
    double d = 0.0;
    std::stringstream stream (doubleStr);
    stream >> d;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(2)<<  d << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

http://cpp.sh/9lub

about comparing float point numbers you may look at this [What is the most effective way for float and double comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison)